# Converting Puppet DSL to Yaml - how to get the same list item twice?

Tags: puppet, filebeat

I have a puppet class I am configuring:

```
    class { 'filebeat':
      modules => [
        module => 'apache',
        module => 'iptables',
        ],
      ],
    }
```

I am trying to output the following:

```
filebeat:
  modules:
    - module: apache
    - module: iptables
```

However, having the two items both named "module" causes the second one to overwrite the first. The actual output I get is:

```
filebeat:
  modules:
    - module: iptables
```

How can I edit my Puppet code such that I generate the desired yaml output with multiple module entries?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
    class { 'filebeat':
      modules => [
        { module => 'apache' } ,
        { module => 'auditd' } ,
      ],
    }
```

Comment: To be clear: quite apart from any consideration of YAML conversion, the syntax of the class declaration presented in the the question is invalid.  The syntax presented in this answer is valid, but whether it is appropriate for the specific class being declared depends on that class.